# Advice on how to handle syncing multiple Trello boards' due dates with Android?

Tags: trello, google-calendar, trello-cards, google-tasks

I really like the visual presentation/interface of Trello versus other ticket boards or project collaboration platforms that have been too large for my needs.  I've been using it for about five months but still feel new with it. I am still trying to figure out how to work around some of the current limitations of due dates and mobile access to the platform.

Ideally, I would LOVE a way to synchronise Trello due dates as tasks instead of as a calendar and then have a widget or app dashboard that could display the tasks like Todoist can, filtered and grouped as `Overdue`, then `Today`, then `next 5 days`.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Ideally without paying for a third party, but I'm not entirely against it as long as it's not some sort of per edit fee system since I'll always be altering dates and only be increasing card use over time.

*See below for my usage structure, tools and attempted calendar tools*

---

#### Current Usage

- Three Organizations

  - *Solo user currently for all boards - no assigns*
  - 1-3 boards each for now that I want to sync due dates/reminders for

    - Personal life
    - My Business (build/expand/structure)
    - My Primary Client

#### Primary Access Tools

- Chrome or Firefox on Win 7 *Chrome only Add-ons for visual cues, though they impact title display in any other access*
- iPad : Official App
- Android Smartphone

  - DigiCal+

    - *to be able to use color code per calendar but also can alter individual appts,
    - join multiple calendars for widget views (can only display all calendars synced)*
  - PureGrid/PureCal Widgets

    - to build widgets for select calendars only

#### Calendar streaming

**Trello build in Calendar feed creation**

- 1 per Board
- DISPLAYS AS

  - Title = Card Title [List Name], Location = Board Title, Description = Card URL, Assigned Members and timestamp of last feed update
- PROS

  - Includes List Name
  - Seems to be updated faster. (Not sure if that's because the Android Tools/Widgets can request sync updates or if it's due to the native Trello feed)
- CONS

  - All due date times are set for 1 hour
  - Requires keeping 6-8 more Google Calendars managed (already have 4-6 between existing Google calendars, an old Touchdown calendar, people, Facebook etc)

***Alternate Options***

**[Trello2iCal Feed](http://fun.sveder.com/trello)**

- creates a stream of some/all boards
- Currently set up 1 feed for all boards with dates
- *Feed is then imported to GOOGLE as an external Calendar*

  - Syncable with iPad Calendars and Smartphone
  - Can add notifications to appear before due dates (default set to 5 days, 1.5 days, 3 hours)
- DISPLAYS AS

  - Title = Card Title, Location = Board Title, Description = Card URL
- PROS

  - can choose a single color on Android to represent Trello tasks vs true calendar events
  - Doesn't require card assignments
  - Event length can be 0 minutes
- CONS

  - Subject to sync timing limitations, not immediate, seems to be roughly once a day so when update/push out dates, can't prevent notifications or get phone to display correct data until the following day.

**Trello Android App**

- Widget requires cards to be assigned to you *( I don't have any card assignments on any boards)*
- Looks like they list cards, but wasting a lot of screen space for each?

**Trelloid Android App**

- Widget requires cards to be assigned to you *( I don't have any card assignments on any boards)*
- No list widget, flippable type cards only